# Pulling Out Data Consistently Via Arrays with Formatter?

Tags: arrays, formatter, zapier

Is there any formatter option that would help with pulling out data from arrays? I'm completely stumped here.

This is the array coming in from the Help Scout webhook:
[image]

I’m trying to somehow pull out specifically the Value for fieldID: 10045 (Asana ID).

I can’t seem to figure anything out (it’s the native webhook functionality of Help Scout coming over and they didn’t have any solutions either.)

I’d guess that some sort of “Formatter” should allow you to clean up this info and make it more usable? If there was an option that could just allow you to pick an item from the array 0,1,2,3,4,5 (this isn't consistent though because if say "Due Date" is empty, then it will only have an array with 4 items instead of 5) or rather, based on the first array value (e.g. fieldID: 10045) and then return the rest as strings:

- label: 770617724077919
- name: Asana ID
- type: NUMBER
- value: 770617724077919

I went ad-nauseam with Help Scout and they weren’t able to come up with a solution for being able to grab a specific value out from their messy custom fields array sent via webhook

Maybe utilizing custom javascript via a code snippet was another option I was thinking through?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to do this using the split text function of the Formatter?

There is an article here that shows how to do this - https://zapier.com/help/formatter/#using-split-text-to-extract-data

If the Asana group is always going to be at the end, you can split at `fieldId:` and get the last segment first. In another Formatter step, you can use [:newline:] and get the first segment to get the value for the `fieldId` from the Asana block.

[image: zap]

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion! The thing is, the order it shows up totally changes depending on how many custom fields are there, actually filled out, and how many custom fields are in any given mailbox. I don't think we can really look at this based on the structure of the data because that changes based on tons of factors. I'm shocked that Zapier doesn't have some type of way to better handle arrays :/